# Unable to open and access Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt, windows-11

I am trying to run the command prompt, but it is not opening. I even tried running it as an administrator and also from the folder. The error persists.
What should I do?

I wanted to add power plans: ultimate and high performance. But it requires command prompt which is not accessible.